# How to measure memory consumption in Azure web roles

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-monitoring

The Azure management dashboard gives you the possibility to monitor metrics such as CPU utilization, network in/out, response time, among others.

But how can you measure consumption/availability of memory? I am running a web app that is memory intensive, and it is hard for me to gauge which instance types (or number of instances) I should provision without having an understanding of the memory situation across time.

Yes, my service is a web role on Azure cloud services, I **am not** talking about VMs (IaaS) here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Azure project, in the Roles folder you'll find a folder for each of your Roles. If you use the latest version of the SDK you'll find a file called **diagnostics.wadcfg**. This is where you'll be able to configure Performance Counters, like **\Memory\Available Bytes**. This file will also allow you to configure the sample rate (ex: every 30 sec) and the scheduled transfer period (how frequently the logs should be transferred to your Storage Account).

Then you can use a tool like the [Azure Diagnostics Manager](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-diagnostics-manager/introduction) to view memory consumption over time.

More information: [Using performance counters in Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-use-performance-counters/)

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this from the Management Console:

- On the Configure tab for your web role, in the **monitoring** section, change **level** to Verbose.
- On the Monitor tab at the bottom, click Add Metrics

With monitoring set to Verbose, the available metrics should include Memory Available.